# databinding must include a layout file

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

I have following very simple layout and wanted to switch to using data binding. Now I'm getting following error in my `controller_main.xml`:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingProcessLayoutsDebug_pro'.
```

> ****/ data binding error ****msg:[44 68 44 68 25] must include a layout
>   file:...\app\src\main\res\layout\controller_main.xml
>   ****\ data binding error ****

Any ideas? The error says, the resource `android:layout` id in the `include` tag is missing (that's my interpretation of the error), but that's not true. Commenting out the `include` tag removes the error.

Does anyone see the problem?

**controller_main.xml**

```
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="?attr/main_background_color"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlContent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </RelativeLayout>

        <include
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/tool_bar_top_padding"
            android:id="@+id/stub_view_main_header_fixed"
            android:layout="@layout/view_main_header_fixed"
            app:elevation="0dp"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</layout>
```

**view_main_header_fixed.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<View
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/vStatusbarBackground"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/tool_bar_top_padding" />
```

Comment: `"id in the include tag is missing"`, whats unclear in this?

Comment: You see the include? It is defining an id. And I don't know where you have the `"id in the include tag is missing"` from... It says layout is missing. But the layout is defined as well. The problem is solved anyways already...

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You should use `layout` instead of `android:layout`:

```
<include
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/tool_bar_top_padding"
        android:id="@+id/stub_view_main_header_fixed"
        layout="@layout/view_main_header_fixed"
        app:elevation="0dp"/>
```

Comment: found that out already ;-) thanks. Was something that came from changing from using `ViewStubs` to mutliple layouts with includes...

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same error, but for a different reason.
I was using `<include>` opening tag and `</include>` closing tag instead of `<include` for opening and `/>` for closing. It's little strange, but anyway your question helped me find my mistake. Thanks.